# How to insert arange values to pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

**Hello everyone**, I'm trying to upload the co-ordinates of a particular place which I have generated using arange in numpy. Now I want to upload all those generated values to mongo atlas. From the below code I was able to upload 1 value at a time. But i need help in uploading all the generated lat at a time. Your answers would be highly appreciated

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username><pass>@cluster0-tcuuq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["dbname"]
collection = db["collection_name"]

post = { 'Lat': 12.941313}

collection.insert_one(post)
```

I'm generating lat values like below

```
a = np.arange(12.941313, 12.941466, 0.000001)
a_float = [float("{:.6f}".format(lat)) for lat in a]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [pymongo doc](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) and insert_many function in collection

Replace post by posts as an array of dicts containing your values and use insert_many instead of insert_one over posts

```
posts = [{'Lat': your lat 1} <all your lats>]
collection.insert_many(posts)
```

Comment: Thank you @R.LM for replying. Since I have more than 100 values to fill it takes lot of time. Also i need to upload Long also. Is there any method where i can map the word "Lat" with the generated Lats using arange

Comment: Try to use python inline for function like so posts = [{'Lat': af} for af in a_float]. If my answers seems good too you accept it by ticking the green check on my answer